# Given three points on a plane and two points on a line that intersects the plane. I need the angle between the plane and the line.

Tags: geometry

A real world problem where the angular orienation of the axis of a feature to a reference plane is needed but is absent from a blueprint. Thank you.

Comment: Can you give us any specific details about the numbers?

Comment: The only thing we need for that is the orthogonal projection of a segment of the line on the plane, join both feet (the line's and its projection's) and the angle is the one between the line and the one joining the feet.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to augurar's answer, but using vector products:

Let $p_1, p_2, p_3$ be the points defining the plane, and let $l_1, l_2$ be the points defining the line.

1. Let $\vec{a_1} = p_1-p_3$ and $\vec{a_2} = p_2-p_3$.
2. Let $\vec{c} = \vec{a_1} \times \vec{a_2}$ so $\vec{c}$ is orthogonal to the plane.
3. Let $\vec{u} = l_1 - l_2$.
4. Angle is $\cos^{-1}\left(\left|\dfrac{\vec{c} \cdot \vec{u}}{|c||u|}\right|\right)$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch of how you can compute this.

Let $p_1, p_2, p_3$ be the points defining the plane, and let $l_1, l_2$ be the points defining the line.

1. Let $a_1 = p_1-p_3$ and $a_2 = p_2-p_3$.
2. Let $b_1 = a_1$ and let $b_2$ be the component of $a_2$ orthogonal to $b_1$.
3. Let $u = l_1 - l_2$.
4. Let $v$ be the orthogonal projection of $u$ onto $b_1$ and $b_2$.
5. Compute the angle between $u$ and $v$.